# Qual a diferença entre [a] e "a" em Haskhell?

Tags: haskell

Isto está correto??

`[a]` = uma lista com 1 só elemento
`a` = uma lista com quantos elementos quiser

Ps: tenho algumas duvidas porque algumas funcoes sao do tipo `[a]->a` 
mas leem tambem , por exemplo `[2,3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está correto, quando uma função qualquer diz `func :: [a] -> a` está nos informando que ela pega como parâmetro uma lista qualquer (de qualquer tamanho) e retorna um elemento do mesmo tipo da lista. A variável **a** pode ser de qualquer tipo, se a lista for de números então o resultado será um número.

Vejamos um exemplo:

O escopo da função *head* em Haskell (`:t head`):

```
head :: [a] -> a
head [1,2,3] -- 1
head [a,b,c] -- a
```

Essa função retorna o primeiro elemento de uma lista (cabeça da lista). Pode ser uma lista de qualquer tamanho, basta testar para verificar.

Já a função *tail*, que retorna a cauda da lista, tem um escopo ligeiramente diferente:

```
tail :: [a] -> [a]
tail [1,2,3] -- [2,3]
tail [a,b,c] -- [b,c]
```

Visto que a cauda pode ter 0 ou mais elementos.

Se fosse uma função do tipo Equals seria algo assim:

```
eq :: a -> a -> Bool
```

Ou seja, recebe dois parâmetros do mesmo tipo e retorna true/false.
Para aprender mais sobre Haskell recomendo este [livro online](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/introduction).

Comment: Muito obrigado :p , ja entendi

Comment: Poderia marcar a resposta como aceita? Embaixo das setas ^ v tem um OK verde.